# A script command asks for username. Can I have it stored inside the script?

Tags: shell

I have this command inside a script.

```
sudo openvpn --config ....
```

When it is executed it asks for a username, and then for a password.
Is it possible to store inside the script the username?

In other words to avoid typing it each time this script is being executed?

(I am using Linux Ubuntu)

Comment: just create a variable containing the username and use that in the script:`USER=bob` then use the variable `$USER` where it is needed.

Comment: I would imagine you could put that information in the openvpn config directly somehow too.

Comment: @EtanReisner, ...well, kinda'. For good reason, OpenVPN discourages anything that would put credentials directly on the command line, and the command line and config file formats have full equivalency with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the configuration directive

```
auth-user-pass filename
```

...where `filename` is a file with username on the first line, and password on the second. (If you don't want the password to ever touch disk, this password can be a socket on which your script passes through user input).

For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^- IMPORTANT: use bash, not /bin/sh

# clearing IFS and using read -r makes trailing whitespace, literal backslashes, etc. work.
username="hardcoded value"
IFS= read -r -p "Password: " password
openvpn \
  --config file.ovpn \
  --auth-user-pass <(printf '%s\n' "$username" "$password")
```

The use of `printf` -- a builtin -- is important here: When calling only builtins, arguments aren't placed on the argv (and thus made accessible to anything on the system inspecting the process list).

---

Alternately, you can use the `management-query-passwords` directive [or the `--management-query-passwords` command-line option] to allow username and password to be requested and entered via the management socket (this protocol [has its own extensive documentation](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/79-management-interface.html)).

Comment: I don't understand why I have to user IFS commands. When I do so it is prompted twice to enter the username and password.

Comment: @caa, it's a `read` command, not an `IFS` command, getting values from the user; `IFS` changes how `read` works, fixing support for values with trailing whitespace. Anyhow, you can get those values from anywhere -- if you want to hardcode the username but prompt for the password, just put `username=foo` in place of that `read`, and leave the one for the password in place. If you want to get them from a file, or a serial port, or, well, whatever -- that's your edit to make. :)

Comment: Ok thank you first of all!
I tried doing that but a get an error Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tap:

Another question. Why do I need the auth-user-pass file if I hardcode the vars inside script?

Comment: `<()` creates a "file" inline (actually a named pipe, so your raw password data doesn't hit disk), so when you're using that, you don't need a separate, hardcoded file. Beyond that, the answer comes down to "because that's the upstream-defined interface for programmatically feeding usernames and passwords to openvpn".

Comment: Re: the `TUNSETIFF` error, that sounds like you didn't use `sudo`. If you aren't putting `sudo` in front of this script, then put it in the script: `sudo openvpn ...`

Comment: yes thanks it was the sudo issue. I made it work by actually having a file with the username. It quite strange that the printf command does not work...

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible.  You have use the pipe `|` and pipe the username to the scripts beginning if it is possible.  I use a command in C++, which if I remember right changes the password for the user. It  looks like:

```
sprintf(command, "echo -e \"%s\n%s\" | passwd %s",password,password,user);
```

So, since this is a shell, I would guess you could do something like:

```
 echo -e '<username>\n<password>\n' | YourScript
```

In your case this may work:

```
echo -e `<username>\n<password>\n | sudo openvpn --config...
```

Of course, this assumes that there are no other things it will ask for.  This is also untested.  [Read more on piping here](http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/piping.php).

**Edit:**

As mentioned by Charles Duffy the above will only work with an XSI-extended system and with programs that do not rely on TTY.  I'm still not 100% certain but, I ready `printf` was cross compatible and `script -c` can be used to pipe tty.  [Here is the information on the script command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html).  However, trying it in CentOS7, it looks like this would work:

```
printf '%s\n' "username" "password" | script -c "sudo openvpn --config..."
```

*NOTE:* I tried only piping to `su` and it worked after POSIXLY_CORRECT was set to 1.

Also, I think I may have misunderstood exactly what you wanted to do.  If you wanted to store the username and password for the duration of the script you could do something like this:

```
printf "Input username:"
read username

printf "Input password:"
read -s password

printf '%s\n' "$username" "$password" | script -c "sudo openvpn --config..."
```

Comment: Well-behaved programs prompt for security-sensitive information from the TTY, not stdin. Also, OpenVPN has out-of-band means for receiving username and password.

Comment: ...also, using `echo -e` unnecessarily is bad form. What if a password contains a literal backslash? `echo -e` would eat it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree that it may not be optimal.  However, I would argue if they were hard coding the value they should or would know if they wanted a literal backslash they would use '\\' as mentioned by http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo.  I'm not extremely familiar with Linux so I'm still researching the other point.

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section -- the `echo` behavior you're depending on directly contradicts the POSIX standard. Yes, GNU violates the standard (by behaving as if it were an XSI-extended POSIX system if `-e` were present, and a non-XSI system without) -- but a plain reading of the standard requires `echo -e` to literally print `-e`.

Comment: ...incidentally, if `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` (an environment variable which was almost named `POSIX_ME_HARDER`, had someone not reigned in RMS's sense of humor) is set in the environment, GNU coreutils echo will behave as a non-XSI, POSIX-compliant implementation, printing `-e` literally; try running `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 /bin/echo -e 'hello\nworld'`. Some UNIX systems will do the same out-of-the-box; others won't; witness the dangers of relying on `echo`.

Comment: Your C++ code, btw, would be much more secure if you used `popen()` to call `passwd` and wrote the password directly into the input pipe itself. As it is, you're putting the raw password on the command line of the shell invoked when you call `system()` with that string for any process on the system to read. (It may be there only in transient form -- if you're lucky, your `/bin/sh` overwrites argv after it's done starting up to obscure its command line from other processes -- but even then, relying on attackers to have bad timing isn't a great strategy).

Comment: ...also, I hope you're checking for usernames or passwords that contain `$(rm -rf /)`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy those are good points about the C++ part.  But, as it stands it is a hobby project that I haven't worked on for a while.  If I ever do get back to it, I'll try to remember what you've said.

Comment: Re: edits -- `printf '%s\n' "username" "password"` is better form than putting the raw data into format strings (think about what happens if a password contains `%` signs).

Comment: Quotes are still important, by the way -- leave them out and passwords with whitespace or glob characters may misbehave.

Comment: Thank you as well for your response. I got some errors doing it this way. 
Just one question. Is option script -c necessary?

Comment: @caa Sorry, I'm not extremely familiar with Linux.  From what I understand it is necessary because of TTY.  As far as the errors go, I would not be surprised if it comes down to sudo.  Make sure you are starting your script with sudo.  If you have to, you could run it as root by using ```sudo su```, to become root, but that is not recomended.

Comment: @caa, re: the `script -c`, whether it's necessary depends on whether OpenVPN is reading from stdin or the TTY. You'll need to test for your version -- I don't see anything explicit in the docs, so it could go either way (or try the TTY and fall back to stdin).